# PHP: Merging images into an alpha translucent image with GD

Tags: php, image-processing, transparency, gd

I'm trying to create an image with varying level of transparency, using GD. But I can get only fully transparent or fully opaque pixels in the image.

What I want to get:                                                      What I actually get:
[image]
<sub>(source: [bx.at.ua](http://bx.at.ua/i/se/stackoverflow/target.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [bx.at.ua](http://bx.at.ua/i/se/stackoverflow/actual.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [bx.at.ua](http://bx.at.ua/i/se/stackoverflow/target-zoom.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [bx.at.ua](http://bx.at.ua/i/se/stackoverflow/actual-zoom.png))</sub>

Here's a piece of the <s>code I used to create images like this one ▲</s> fixed code:

`$im=imagecreatetruecolor($sx,$sy);`
<s>`imageantialias($im,true);`</s>
`imagesavealpha($im,true);`

`$c00FF00=imagecolorallocate($im,0,255,0);`
<s>`$cFFFFFF=imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);`</s>
`$cFFFFFF_00=imagecolorallocatealpha($im,255,255,255,127);`
<s>`imagecolortransparent($im,$cFFFFFF);`</s>

`imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,$sx,$sy,`<s>`$cFFFFFF`</s>`$cFFFFFF_00);`

```
$sim=imagecreatefrompng('gradient.png');
imagecopy($im,$sim,$dest_x,$dest_y,0,0,imagesx($sim),imagesy($sim));
imagedestroy($sim);

imagettftext($im,$size,0,$text_x,$text_y,$c00FF00,$font,'Test');

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

<s>What can I do to get the desired (translucent) result?</s>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `imagesavealpha()` against your imported PNG ($sim) before merging, as well as against the final image.

Comment: I need to experiment with it, because now I got an opposite result: white background with transparent images :D

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not transparency but alpha. Alpha is another color channel that goes along with the red, green and blue colors to determine the transparency level (just transparent is visible or not as opposed to being able to set the level of transparency). Check out [imagecolorallocatealpha](http://www.php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha)

Comment: This does not answer the question... At least, you gave me a hint that I should edit the title

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to add transparency to the text, in which case you would use the imagecolorallocatealpha when setting the $c00FF00 variable. The images you put in your request just give me a time out error and so I couldn't see the example images.